# How can we implement if -goto loops in C++?

Tags: c++, loops

We were taught about **if goto** loops in school. The program given by instructor doesnt work. By doesnt work I mean that it gets compiled, but when i execute it, the output is nothing :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    prev: i++;             // prev label
    cout << "a ";
    if(i < 20) { goto prev; }
    return 0;
}
```

The actual loop to be implemented in was equivalent to this for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    cout << "a ";
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: your program works .. look at http://ideone.com/ZqeoXi

Comment: @tobi303 The program gets compiled, but there is no output (although i used cout)

Comment: My psychic powers tell me we need a `cout << endl;` line right before the `return 0;`

Comment: @Kevin No you don't, it'll be buffered on program exit. The program is fine as is (modulo usual caveats about using `goto`)

Comment: i am not the fastest one, but I can also [confirm](http://ideone.com/kZ4A7E) that it works

Comment: We don't _absolutely_ need it (just copy-pasted the source and compiled with VC9 and it gives the desired output) but some systems might not show any output without it.  (Or, depending how you're running it, might close the output window before you can see it).

Comment: The 2 programs aren't exactly equivalent: if instead of `cout << "a ";` you had `cout << i << " ";` you would notice that the version with the `for` loop prints numbers from 0 to 19, whereas the version with `goto` prints numbers from 1 to 20. Of course if you just print `a` you don't see the difference, but there *is* one.

Comment: _How can we implement if -goto loops in C++?_ We should almost never do this. If we are to do this, we should probably only use it to go to a forward location where we exit the function. (That won't win you any points with your instructor at this time though.)

Comment: @everyone ... Why is no output shown on windows 8 g++?

Comment: How are you running the program? From the command line? Double-clicking its icon? From your IDE?

Answer (score 4):

The problem with the given program is that the value of `i` is incremented at the beginning of the loop, and the check is performed at the end; thus, it will increment before the first iteration, and always execute at least one iteration. The following would more accurately reflect the given `for` loop:

```
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    next: if(!(i < 20)) goto end;
    cout << "a ";
    i++;
    goto next;
    end: return 0;
}
```

For the most part, labels and gotos are rarely used - they result in harder to follow code, are only ways to make while/for/if blocks (such as here) about 99% of the time, and are most useful to know in order to better understand the compiler's job and how your code relates to the machine code it generates.

Comment: Thanks but I was asking why it was not showing output under Windows 8 (g++)

Comment: @Avavol you're right but how does what you've posted either address the question that was asked? If you don't feel it addresses what the question is looking for then it should be posted as a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how *fast* you are, you may not *notice* the programs output, because it does not wait for the user. It just closes. You should make it wait for you to observe it's runtime behavior:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int i = 0;
prev:             // prev label
    i++;
    cout << "a ";
    if(i < 20) 
    {
        goto prev; 
    }

    // wait for the user to press [enter]
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Otherwise you can run it from a shell (run `cmd`). This way, when the program ends, the window isn't closed automatically, it just stays there, giving you the time to check the result.

Answer (score 1):

THanks to everyone very much. I was using WIndoes 8 with g++.

The problem was that I was using the **filename** to execute the application. When I used **filename.exe** to execute, it executed succesfully and showed the output. THanks to everyone!